# Apply formula to column using values from other column

Tags: pandas

If I have a `df`:

```
mean games
0.3  18
0.4  8
...
```

and I want to apply a formula that adds some scalar values like `alpha = 1.2` and `beta = 0.5`, I can do this:

```
df['mean'] = df['mean'].apply(lambda x: x+alpha+beta)
```

How can I also apply each correspondent 'games' value to the formula, for each x? For example:

```
alpha+0.3/18+alpha+beta
alpha+0.4/8+alpha+beta
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it almost as you did (`alpha+0.3/18+alpha+beta`):

```
df['result'] = alpha+df['mean']/df['game']+alpha+beta
```

Mathematically equivalent to:

```
df['result'] = 2*alpha+beta + df['mean']/df['game']
```

(unless you forgot parentheses)